# cordova giving TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA_URL' of undefined:68

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am using the cordova test project to make an app with eclipse.

I followed the following steps (these are inside the README inside the cordova-3.3.0 /cordova-android folder).

---

Importing a Cordova Android Project into Eclipse

1. File > New > Project...
2. Android > Android Project
3. Create project from existing source (point to the generated app found in tmp/android)
4. Right click on libs/cordova.jar and add to build path
5. Right click on the project root: Run as > Run Configurations
6. Click on the Target tab and select Manual (this way you can choose the emulator or device to build to)

   ---

The projects i tried are:
 cordova-3.3.0\cordova-android\framework
 cordova-3.3.0\cordova-android\test

I keep getting the same kind of error: 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA_URL' of undefined:68

I even tried full example code from :

```
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera
```

Comment: When you use Eclipse, why don't you use Eclipse to create the project as well?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try building the app (`cordova build`) again after installing the plugin. Let me know if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes just trying "phonegap build ios" or "phonegap build android" for a SECOND time is needed. At least that works for me.

It has something to do with the InAppBrowser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having same experience running "phonegap build android" twice to get it to compile.
From my own experience, it was InAppBrowser plugin that is causing this to happen.